# Trying to print a list from a text file?

Tags: java, list, file

I'm trying to print a list of actors and The program is printing all the names but I am getting a  error. I need help finding a way to print the names to which the program will end the while loop after the last name.

Here is the list:

```js
Leonardo Dicaprio
Susan Sarandon
Tom Hanks
Robert De Niro
Barack Obama
Helen Keller
Katharine Cornell
Helen Hayes
John Laughlin
Mark Zuckerberg
Joe Lipari
Welker White
```

This is my program:

```js
public void printActors() 
 
   throws FileNotFoundException
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("actors"));
   String line = null;
   while ((line = input.nextLine()) != null) 
     {
         System.out.println(line);
     }
  
 
 }
```

This is the output:

```js
Leonardo Dicaprio
Susan Sarandon
Tom Hanks
Robert De Niro
Barack Obama
Helen Keller
Katharine Cornell
Helen Hayes
John Laughlin
Mark Zuckerberg
Joe Lipari
Welker White
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at Game.BaconGame.main(BaconGame.java:26)
```

Can someone help me out so It can print the names on the list and get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2):

Use `while (input.hasNextLine())` to check whether a line exists in the input stream (`Scanner` doesn't return `null` if a line is not found, it throws `NoSuchElementException`)

I strongly recommend using `FileReader` and `BufferedReader` if you just want to read a file and not *parse* it.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("actors");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
     String line=br.readLine() ;
    while (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
        line=br.readLine() ;
    }
    in.close();
```

or as per your code

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("actors"));
while ((input.hasNextLine())) 
           {
               System.out.println(input.nextLine());
           }
```

Comment: You are calling `br.readLine()` twice, it will skip line for which you are checking *not null*.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            String line;
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("actors"));
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null)
                    bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public void printActors() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("c:\\actors.txt"));

      while(input.hasNextLine())
      {

        System.out.println(input.nextLine());
      }
    }
```

Comment: Code dumps do not help. Please try including comments/explanation as well.